# Mac/iPad Results in Dropped Blazor Server-side Connections

Tags: macos, ipad, safari, blazor, blazor-server-side

I recently received a report from a Mac/iPad user who used my Blazor server-side application. The problem seems to be that when they put the Safari browser in the background (e.g. switching to another application like Twitter to talk with me), the application disconnects:

[image: Reconnect Message]

This does not occur with any device/browser combination that I have tried with Windows (my native/development environment).

I am in the process of acquiring an iPad to test this on in my local environment, but I am wondering if anyone out there has had any experience with this and/or if there is a remedy to it.

Any assistance/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have answers to why it does this (other than presumably power saving) but you can configure your own reconnection handler in the JS world for Blazor that gives you more control and the ability to automatically reload when this happens - if you can't figure out how to stop it

Comment: Thank you @MisterMagoo your assistance/insight is appreciated.  The customer is located in India, so I am curious if there is a latency/hop issue occurring here.

Comment: Seems to happen a lot on here, @MisterMagoo.  I appreciate your assistance and insight in the face of it, in any case.  As you can see by the answer/reddit thread, this is a known issue and I have provided a Github issue that is tracking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this Reddit thread, this appears to be due to a known issue:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/x78buq/blazor_serverside_safarimacipad_connection_issue/

It is captured here in this issue with Github:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30344